# When someone sends a command in discord.js it spits out errors instead of sending a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
  client.on('message', message => {
      if (!message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("Hey! Dont try to make me say that!")
      if (message.content.startsWith("||say ")) { //prefix
      message.delete(1); //Supposed to delete message
      message.channel.send(message.content.slice(5, message.content.length));
   }
});
```

So when i tested this on a account with no perms, the command didn't go through but it spits out errors instead of sending the message that you cannot make the bot send messages. Here is the error https://pastebin.com/raw/UFH7wKCd
Also, the delete message doesn't work on the code.

Comment: `message.delete()` takes an object: [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete).

Comment: Also, the code in the error is different to the code you pasted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I added a filter to prevent the bot from responding to it's own message and an async/await.

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return await message.channel.send("Hey ! Dont try to make me say that !")
    if (message.content.startsWith("||say ")) { // prefix
        message.delete(1); // Supposed to delete message
        message.channel.send(message.content.slice(5, message.content.length));
    }
});
```

Comment: when I use this it spams the message to everyone without the perms

Comment: I fixed it by removing the message "Hey ! Dont try to make me say that"